# Realistic Material viewport without rendering?

Tags: materials, interface

I would like to see my materials & the actual lights in the material so it looks as render but with no rendering and in a viewport mode. Is there anyway I can do this? Are there any other options

Comment: PBR materials in Blender viewport are the closest you can get to render. Here is how to setup them: https://cgcookie.com/2015/05/20/pbr-in-blenders-viewport/. There is also a Blender custom build with easier PBR integration: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343278-GLSL-PBR-Shader-for-viewport

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way you could explain it to me step by step? It's a little bit confusing for me

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to have real: *transparent raytracing, mirroring, subsurface scattering, generated texture coordinates, multiple light bounces*

Set the 3D View Shading to *Material*. In the *Display* section of the Properties Panel check "Only Render" and "World Background". In the *Shading* section select GLSL shading and check ambient occlusion.

In the Viewport you can use the Blender Game Shaders / Lights.

Utilize Texture baking all Textures Channels except Specular/Glossy.

There are many different techniques to fake rendering effects.

I advise you to check out these two tutorials:

- [Viewport Rendering](https://agenzasbrothers.com/en/quick-viewport-rendering-in-blender-tutorial/): Blender Game Engine Material
- [Hacking The Viewport](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/12/18/blender-2-7-hacking-the-viewport/): Many Hacks and Fake Effects

EDIT: Jerryno's comment suggests [PBR](https://cgcookie.com/2015/05/20/pbr-in-blenders-viewport/), which is an important resource as well.